# Rename Multi-FASTA sequence headers using Master File of similar names

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have multiple FASTA files that are using very simple headers which identify the specimen. However, I would like to make the headers much more detailed by adding geographic location, source and culture date.

My first thought is to use `stringr` package in `R` to read in each FASTA and replace any matching sequence ID with the appropriate string.

Using a .xlsx with the necessary data and specimen ID I can create a .txt with a series of strings with the new names I desire. Using this "Master Text" file I would like to rename each of the sequences in each FASTA appropriately through matching the Specimen ID.

So I created `rename.txt` in the following format:

```
SpecimenID|ST|Geographic Location|Source|CultDate
VRE32491|736|PUH - 10C|Blood|2016-12-07
VRE32493|1471|PUH - 10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08
VRE32503|1471|PUH - 11N|Wound|2017-01-05
VRE32504|1471|PUH - EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10
VRE32514|1471|PUH - 6F|Wound|2017-01-20
```

Using `Biostrings::readDNAStringSet(*.fasta)` I am able to obtain the names for each sequence using `names()` on the object. I want to create a matching string from `rename.txt` that will enable me to simply rename the DNAStringSet object using `names({DNAStringSet object}) <- {matching string}`.

What my problem is that I can't seem to extract a character string set from the `rename.txt`.

Below is some code anyone can use for a reprex to simulate my issue:

```
cat(
  ">VRE32493", "AGCT",
  ">VRE32503", "CAGT",
  ">VRE32504", "TCAA",
  file = "example.fasta", sep = "\n"
)

cat(
  "SpecimenID|ST|Geographic Location|Source|CultDate",
  "VRE32491|736|PUH - 10C|Blood|2016-12-07",
  "VRE32493|1471|PUH - 10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08",
  "VRE32503|1471|PUH - 11N|Wound|2017-01-05",
  "VRE32504|1471|PUH - EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10",
  "VRE32514|1471|PUH - 6F|Wound|2017-01-20",
  file = "example.txt", sep = "\n"
)

origMult <- Biostrings::readDNAStringSet("example.fasta")
fasta_rename <- read.delim("example.txt", skip = 1, header = F)
```

Expected output of `example.fasta`:

```
>VRE32493|1471|PUH - 10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08
AGCT
>VRE32503|1471|PUH - 11N|Wound|2017-01-05
CAGT
>VRE32504|1471|PUH - EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10
TCAA
```

Comment: @RonakShah You may have faced issues installing `Biostrings` because it requires `Biocmanager`. [You can find the installation code on this web page](https://rdrr.io/bioc/Biostrings). As for the expected output I will edit my OP shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to assistance elsewhere worked out this solution.

```
cat(
  ">VRE32493", "AGCT",
  ">VRE32503", "CAGT",
  ">VRE32504", "TCAA",
  file = "example.fasta", sep = "\n"
)

cat(
  "SpecimenID|ST|Geographic Location|Source|CultDate",
  "VRE32491|736|PUH - 10C|Blood|2016-12-07",
  "VRE32493|1471|PUH - 10N|Tissue/Surgical|2016-12-08",
  "VRE32503|1471|PUH - 11N|Wound|2017-01-05",
  "VRE32504|1471|PUH - EMEP|Blood|2017-01-10",
  "VRE32514|1471|PUH - 6F|Wound|2017-01-20",
  file = "example.txt", sep = "\n"
)

# Read in from example.txt
fasta_rename <- readr::read_file("example.txt")
fasta_rename <- unlist(strsplit(fasta_rename, "\\r"))
fasta_rename <- stringr::str_remove(fasta_rename[-1], "\\n")
fasta_rename <- fasta_rename[-length(fasta_rename)]
# Remove everything after first | to get the pattern to match off of
patterns <- stringr::str_remove(fasta_rename, "\\|(.+)$")
# Make fasta_rename a named character vector in the form of patterns = fasta_rename
names(fasta_rename) <- patterns

fasta_rename # print to verify

example_fasta <- readr::read_file("example.fasta")
example_fasta <- unlist(strsplit(example_fasta, "\\r"))
example_fasta <- stringr::str_remove(example_fasta, "\\n")
example_fasta <- example_fasta[-length(example_fasta)]

example_fasta #print to verify

cat(stringr::str_replace_all(example_fasta, fasta_rename), 
    file = "example.fasta", 
    sep = "\n")
```